# Optimizing multiple select and group by in large PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql

I have two large lists, trips (15 million) and nodes (several million).  Each trip is made up of many nodes - 400 on average.

I am attempting to complete the following process most efficiently as possible, but the performance varies drastically based on the selected node (several seconds to 10 minutes).  The more trips using the selected node, the slower.  Some nodes may have > 10,000 trips using them.

1. User selects a node from map
2. Identify all trips using the node
3. Identify all nodes used by the trips in #2
4. Group the nodes in #3 and produce a count for each
5. Display results on map

I have created a large table (trip_nodes) with the trip ID and node ID as the two columns (both integers) and a row for every node of every trip (6 billion) and I've indexed both columns.  I'm currently querying with the following:

```
SELECT node, count(node) FROM trip_nodes a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM 
trip_nodes WHERE trip_int_id = a.trip_int_id AND node = xxxx) GROUP BY node
```

Do you have any suggestions on ways I can speed up queries of nodes with many trips?  Would adding a primary key help?  Should I use smaller one to many correlation tables (trip_id, list_of_nodes (text))?

I have done some optimization of the postgresql.conf and that has helped, but I don't want users to have to wait multiple minutes for a query to run.